# Top menu depth level different than left categories depth level

Tags: magento2.2, menu

I would like to show in top menu just until 3rd depth level and in left categories sidebar all depth levels. How I supposed to do? Thanks

Comment: please specify that is your Question related to Magento 1x or 2x

Comment: is magento 2.2.1 and the theme is DigitalWorld

Answer (score 1):

Although Magento has provided configuration for setting the maximum depth for category top navigation, but it does not work in Magento 2.1.x and 2.2.x as expected.

This is a bug in Magento 2.2.x and has been fixed in develop branch of Magento 2.3.x.

Reference Link: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7543

You can check the files mentioned in Related commit(s):

```
07233f2
0a6ac4c
b6215b6
15523e8
```

and fix it for the time-being for your shop or wait for the next release to come.

Comment: thx. so, you suggest to upgrade to 2.3.x?

Comment: Create a replica of your website and then upgrade the replica to Magento 2.3.x, so that you are on the safer side if something wrong happens.

Comment: You can also try installing a fresh Magento 2.3.x with sample data to test it.

Comment: Once your test is complete, you can upvote if it helped. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can set it category for Navigation Menu & Layer navigation by below options

Check below category option

> Include in Menu >> "Yes" : It will be show in Navigation menu
>
> Anchor >> "Yes" : It will be show in Layer navigation

You can set it as per your requirement.

Comment: I know this, but if I uncheck "Include in Menu", it is not shown neither in left categories sidebar

Comment: Check it after re-indexing & clear cache.

Comment: thanks, but the same